# JavaFX How to handle events properly when using custom cell factories?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-2, javafx-8

I really apologize if this question doesn't make much sense in your perspective but in my perspective, this is really important to write cleaner and more maintainable code.

I have A.fxml, AController.java (controller class for A.fxml). I have a TableView with custom cell factories defined. I prefer defining my cell factories in a separate class so that I can reuse them if needed. I prefer writing all my event handling code in my controller class. But if I use custom cell factories then I am forced to write the event handling in the cell factory class itself.

Is there a way i can handle the custom cell factory events in my controller class itself? or atleast just throw the event from the custom cell factory class to my controller class and handle?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a object to the factory that determines when an context menu should be opened and that prepares the menu.

Example:

```
public interface CellContextMenuProvider<S, T> {

    /**
     * Prepares the context menu for opening.
     * @param cell the cell the menu was requested for
     * @param menu the menu to prepare
     */
    public void prepareContextMenu(TableCell<S, T> cell, ContextMenu menu);

    /**
     * Checks, if a cell continaing a certain item should have an active context
     * menu.
     * @param empty if the cell is empty
     * @param item the item of the cell
     * @return {@literal true} iff the context menu should be enabled.
     */
    public boolean enableContextMenu(boolean empty, T item);

    /**
     * Prepares the intial menu. This menu must not be empty, otherwise it won't
     * be shown when it's requested for the first time.
     * @param menu the menu to prepare
     */
    public void prepareInitialContextMenu(ContextMenu menu);

}
```

```
public class CellFactory<S, T> implements Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> {

    private final CellContextMenuProvider<S, T> menuProvider;
    private final ContextMenu contextMenu;

    public CellFactory(@NamedArg("menuProvider") CellContextMenuProvider<S, T> menuProvider) {
        this.menuProvider = menuProvider;

        if (menuProvider == null) {
            this.contextMenu = null;
        } else {
            this.contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            menuProvider.prepareInitialContextMenu(contextMenu);
        }

        this.menuEventHandler = evt -> {
            if (this.contextMenu != null) {
                TableCell<S, T> source = (TableCell<S, T>) evt.getSource();
                this.menuProvider.prepareContextMenu(source, this.contextMenu);
            }
        };
    }

    public CellFactory() {
        this(null);
    }

    private final EventHandler<ContextMenuEvent> menuEventHandler;

    @Override
    public TableCell<S, T> call(TableColumn<S, T> param) {
        TableCell<S, T> result = new TableCell<S, T>() {

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(Objects.toString(item, ""));
                setContextMenu(menuProvider != null && menuProvider.enableContextMenu(empty, item) ? contextMenu : null);
            }

        };
        result.setOnContextMenuRequested(menuEventHandler);
        if (menuProvider != null && menuProvider.enableContextMenu(true, null)) {
            result.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

```
public class AController {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Item<Integer>> table;

    public void initialize() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            table.getItems().add(new Item<>(i));
        }
    }    

    public CellContextMenuProvider<Item<Integer>, Integer> getMenuProvider() {
        return new CellContextMenuProvider<Item<Integer>, Integer>() {

            private final MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Say Hello World");

            {
                item.setOnAction(evt -> System.out.println("Hello World"));
            }

            @Override
            public void prepareContextMenu(TableCell<Item<Integer>, Integer> cell, ContextMenu menu) {
            }

            @Override
            public void prepareInitialContextMenu(ContextMenu menu) {
                menu.getItems().setAll(item);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean enableContextMenu(boolean empty, Integer item) {
                // only for odd items
                return !empty && (item % 2) != 0;
            }

        };
    }

}
```

**A.fxml**

```xml
<TableView fx:id="table" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fxml.table.AController">
  <columns>
      <TableColumn prefWidth="159.0" text="C1">
          <cellValueFactory>
              <PropertyValueFactory property="value" />
          </cellValueFactory>
          <cellFactory>
              <CellFactory menuProvider="$controller.menuProvider"/>
          </cellFactory>
      </TableColumn>
  </columns>
</TableView>
```

**Note:** if the context menu is always the same you can also add `EventHandler` properties to the factory and use them like e.g. `onAction` attributes for buttons, which would allow you to pass event handlers of the controller, wich would result in shorter/simpler code.

Comment: Thanks for taking time. Your answer is working. But i'm not sure i understood totally. Let me go through the code and try to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Wouldnt it be possible to give your cell factory a `FunctionalInterface` as parameter with your event handling?(not sure if a good idea tho)

I imagine your code as follow:

Controller:

```
myTableView.setCellFactory(new MyOwnCellFactory<>(() -> { 
    // event handling 
}));
```

MyOwnCellFactory:

```
public MyOwnCellFactory(MyFunctionalInterface myInterface) {
    functionalInterface = myInterface;
}

// something something

functionalInterface.handleEvent();
```

FunctionalInterface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyFunctionalInterface {
    public void handleEvent();
}
```

Not sure if I understand your idea correct. Didnt test the code, just wrote it out of my head.

Comment: Thanks for taking time. I tried your solution and it is working. Few doubts. 1. As you mentioned, is it a good idea? any side effects? 2. What if i'm setting the cellFactory from fxml? 3. How to do the same if i have my cell factory class and cell class implemented separately. I mean i have a ButtonCell class which return the TableCell and i have the ButtonCellFactory class which just invokes the ButtonCell like "return new ButtonCell();" from the call() method of the ButtonCellFactory class. Thanks!

Comment: 1) Not sure about side effects. Well at least you cant have multiple event handler in your functional interface. Therefore you would need to change it if you want to have different event handlers.
2) Guess that wouldnt work that well with this approach
3) I guess you could still forward your FunctionalInterface object down to the cell and do whatever you want to with it (call the eventhandler or whatever)

In the end its probably just an straight forward and easy to understand approach. But the other answer is probably better :)